# Why am I unable to select a Target Framework in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, desktop

This is when creating a new C# WinForms project. I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, and seemingly everything I could find online.

---

[image: Target Framework Selection Box]

---

Other frameworks are installed and are selected appropriately in the Visual Studio installer:

[Installed targeting packs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg2pr.png)
[Selected SDK's in Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6r8B.png)
[Selected Frameworks in the Desktop Development section of Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMmDd.png)

Comment: This looks like .Net core project. Can you tell us which VS version/edition you have exactly and how do you create this so called "winforms" project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because you've created a 'SDK' type project. You need to use the Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) project to target the older frameworks.

[image]

Comment: [Msdn guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-1-create-a-windows-forms-application-project?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks for these, pretty simple fix - I had read that MSDN guide but clearly not well enough. Still should be an issue on Microsoft's end however, as the SDK's for the other frameworks are installed and it seems that they should appear there.

Unless it's yet another attempt by Microsoft to force people to shift, which isn't unheard of *cough* Edge *cough*.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this with an existing project (other than rebuilding the entire thing)?

Comment: @Danimal111 What do you mean? Re-target an existing .NET Framework project, or change an existing SDK-type project back to the older style?

Comment: I have a large VS2015 WinForms App (written a decade ago) and we need to keep it going for about one more year. I was deploying as a clickonce on our domain at work from VS2013 from WinServer2008R2 and have migrated it to WinServ2019 VS2015. Works in Dev on new server, but when I deploy it cannot find the CR reports. (In my setup project there is an ! next to the .NET Framework icon.) Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! @DavidOsborne (.net 4.0 framework)

Comment: @DavidOsborne - I solved this .. I reinstalled the 32 bit version of Crystal for VS on my new dev server and then when I deployed all was right with the world... Thanks for the question...